# How to redirect the post/page id by giving custom redirect url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In my wordpress theme i have included meta box for Title, description and redirect section. I have a input field for the redirect box under every post and page id. If i add any url to a particular page/post id for that redirect box, the particular page/post id should redirect to my own url given in that redirect box. Is there any function to do this? I have searched in stackies and i get the following code. But its not working.

```
function my_permalink_redirect($permalink) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID == your_post_id_here) {
        $permalink = 'http://new-url.com/pagename';
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('get_the_permalink','my_permalink_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_filter( 'the_permalink', 'filter_function_name_7062', 10, 2 );

function filter_function_name_7062( $permalink, $post ){

  global $post;

  if ($post->ID == 684) {

    $permalink = 'http://sample.com/1';
  }

  if ($post->ID == 444) {

    $permalink = 'http://sample.com/2';
  }

  return $permalink;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function my_permalink_redirect($permalink) {
     global $post;
     if ($post->ID == your_post_id_here) {
        $permalink = 'http://new-url.com/pagename';
        wp_redirect("'.$permalink.'", 301); 
        exit; 
     }

}
add_filter('get_the_permalink','my_permalink_redirect');
```

Comment: it is not working.. i have pasted the code in my functions.php file.

Comment: Check now, just removed () from the exit!

Comment: I have updated the code with additional quotes and a 301 redirect parameter, please try now.

Comment: it should work, please make sure that you are specifying the correct post id and try the post id with and without '' (single quotes).

Comment: http://localhost/testing/?p=1. This is my link. here 1 is my post id. so i have changed if ($post->ID == your_post_id_here) to if ($post->ID == 1).. But its not redirecting..